# Cómo puedo colocar una base sqlite (agregar datos)en un fragment en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, fragment

Quisiera agregar en un fragmentActivty, agregar la acciones de guardar datos en el fragment. Pero en lo que tengo duda es como implementar o que código utilizar, para que se pueda colocar en el fragmet.java...Cualquier respuesta me sirve gracias. Esto es lo que llevo en el fragmentActivty.

public class RegistrarFragment extends Fragment  {
        Button btnGuardar;
        EditText etId, etNombres, etTelefono;

```
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registrar, container, false);
            }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        btnGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);
        etId = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etId);
        etNombres = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNombres);
        etTelefono = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);


        final Usuarios ayudabd = new Usuarios(getApplicationContext());//<<--aquí es donde me marca error: no se puede encontrar el método de símbolo getApplicationContext ()

        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = ayudabd.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
                valores.put(AyudaBD.DatosTabla.COLUMNA_ID,etId.getText().toString());
                valores.put(AyudaBD.DatosTabla.COLUMNA_NOMBRES, etNombres.getText().toString());
                valores.put(AyudaBD.DatosTabla.COLUMNA_TELEFONOS, etTelefono.getText().toString());

                Long IdGuardado = db.insert(AyudaBD.DatosTabla.NOMBRE_TABLA, AyudaBD.DatosTabla.COLUMNA_ID, valores);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se guardó el registro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//igual que agui me dice lo mismo

            }
        });

}



}
```

Comment: Según he entendido quieres mostrar los valores de una tabla de base de datos ? Si es asi puedes usar una clase que implemente un baseAdapter y mostrar la lista de valores enun ListView

Comment: He hecho unos cambios, respecto ala petición.

Comment: no modifiques las preguntas si quieres preguntar algo nuevo deberías de hacer una nueva pregunta, de todas formas loque quieres es presentar datos en formato de lista en la pantalla si  no entendí mal no?

Comment: No , solamente quiero colocar la opción de agregar un dato por medio de sqlite y que se muestre por medio de otro fragment estos datos creados, pero .., la duda que tengo es que código se utiliza en un fragmentActivity "Para que guarden los datos" de  forma correcta. Porque tengo 2 errores en el codigo que acabe de poner.Espero tu respuesta

Comment: que errores muestra tu código (logcat)? Veo que quieres 2 cosas, una como guardar los datos a sqlite y otra mostrar esos datos guardados en un fragment

Comment: Estos son los errores que me arroja:Error:(36, 51) error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()
Error:(44, 40) error: package AyudaBD does not exist
Error:(45, 40) error: package AyudaBD does not exist
Error:(46, 40) error: package AyudaBD does not exist
Error:(48, 56) error: package AyudaBD does not exist
Error:(48, 89) error: package AyudaBD does not exist
Error:(49, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: #armen si básicamente es lo que quiero hacer:,)

Comment: Básicamente tienes que tener una clase que extienda de SQLiteOpenHelper que es la encargada de interactuar con la base de datos , para mostra el contenido necesitas hacer una ventana con un listView en el que llamando a la clase antes mencionada recuperes datos en forma de lista y los metes en la la listView no tien mas igual este proyecto en git hub te ayuda: https://github.com/MaQuiNa1995/ListaDeCompra/ en el tiene un ejemplo de como mostrar y recuperar datos de 1 base de datos Sqlite en android

Comment: **lo voy a intentar:D de verdad muchas gracias**

Comment: Hola @MAQuiNa1995, ¿no  me podrías resolver una duda que tengo acerca de tu proyecto que me compartiste el otro día? si fueras muy amable.

Comment: Claro, pero mejor envíame un email, esto se está llendo de las manos con el offtopic (lo tienes en mi perfil)